# PHP variable from other file comes back as NULL

Tags: php, joomla

In one PHP file, I have this code:

```
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/custom/functions.php';
global $testVar;
var_dump($testVar);
```

In the `functions.php` file, I have this at the beginning, followed by a few other functions:

```
function pr($s) {
    echo '<pre>', htmlspecialchars(print_r($s,true)), '</pre>';
}

$testVar = 'hello world';
```

When running the first file, the variable comes back as NULL. I added the `global` bit but it shouldn't be necessary. This is part of a Joomla module but I've never had problems including files before, it should just work like regular PHP. Why might this be happening?

Comment: Does the `function.php` file start with `<?php` ? (just to make sure)

Comment: Only the variables come as NULL? What about the functions?

Comment: The sample produces `string 'hello world' (length=11)` when tested with PHP 5.2.11. Does it work for you if used outside of the Joomla module?

Comment: The `global` keyword shouldn't be used in this case.

Comment: The functions in the second file work fine, and the file starts with `<?php`. I think it's probably because at that point the script would inside one of the Joomla functions, but I'm not why `global` in the first file doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, try to use Joomla's path constants such as [JPATH_BASE](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_find_your_absolute_path) instead of `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`. Joomla has a lot of useful constants, check it's documentation.

I've read your answer, and reading php documentation I tried to find a reason to why you need to use `global` keyword twice.

First, [Variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

```
The scope of a variable is the context within which it is defined. For the most 
part all PHP variables only have a single scope.

(...)

However, within user-defined functions a local function scope is introduced. 
Any variable used inside a function is by default limited to the local 
function scope.
```

The variable isn't in a function scope, so that's why we thought the NULL was a strange behavior.

But then I read [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) and found something interesting:

```
(...)
Any variables available at that line in the calling file will be available 
within the called file, from that point forward. However, all **functions** 
and **classes** defined in the included file have the global scope.
```

I can't see any mention about the variables being global in this paragraph. So,it seens that, being cumbersome or not, your solution is the right thing to do when you want to use global variables like that.

In your situation, if doing this is cumbersome, I would create a simple class. If you have just helper functions in your file, create a `class Util{}` with a lot of methods and $testVar as an attribute.

Comment: You get an fatal error if the file is not found... are errors output to response?

Comment: You're right, it shouldn't even echo "NULL" if there's a problem with $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] since he's using require_once instead of an include statement. My Bad. But the JPATH_BASE is still a good advice.

Comment: The file is included fine and the functions in the file work. asgerhallas is right, it would have given an error if the file wasn't there. Thanks for the tip about `JPATH_BASE` though.

Comment: Yeah the Util class sounds like a neat idea. Really the few bits I'm using are variables that ought to be in the database but since there's only a couple it's much simpler and cleaner to use a config-like file.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution that seems to work: using the `global` keyword both when setting the variable initially, and just before I need to use it.

(However this is quite cumbersome, and I'm still not sure why it happens, so if anyone has a better solution, feel free to post.)

Comment: I think I have an explanation to this behavior. It's not so small so I edited my own answer to explain. What do you think?